# pyInotify performance

Tags: python, pyinotify

I have a very large directory tree I am wanting pyInotify to watch.
Is it better to have pyInotify watch the entire tree or is it better to have a number of watches reporting changes to specific files ?
Thanks

Comment: As with most `performance` related questions: why not just benchmark it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to watch only a few files in a huge tree, it makes sense to watch individual files. On the other hand, if you're going to watch almost all files in the tree, watching the entire tree instead makes sense. To know the point of turn exactly, you must benchmark both to see which one performs better.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. The reason I haven't benchmarked anything yet is that I am still at the planning stage. I was wondering design wise which pyInotify was happier with

Comment: @tranimatronic: That's exactly my answer - What makes `pyinotify` happy depends on the exact situation and can only be deduced by benchmarking.